# SQL remove duplicates if more 2

Tags: sql, duplicates

I have a database that needs filtering.

The database contains rows of employees at various companys who have signed up to a newsletter. I don't wish to send the newsletter to each one, I only want to send it to 2 from each company. what would my SQL be to remove the duplicates if more than 2 from 1 company listed?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Could you also include the database that you are using? It might help with the syntax. (Also: have a quick read of http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5029 as you are new :) )

Comment: which data base ? mysql or sql server  or somthing else?

Comment: How do you decide which two employees get the newsletter? Is it allowed for one employee employed by several companies to get newsletter more than once?

Comment: The best plan for SQL question is to provide: Info on exactly which version of SQL you're using (MySQL? MSSQL? MSSQL 2008?), Example input, example output. What SQL you've already had a go at. If you can also set something up on sqlfiddle.com that's even better.

Comment: Welcome on SO: first of all the DBMS is always one of the most important details, and you should tag it in your question (you can edit it). And try to use table specifications and a requested result (as an example), then for sure you will get a better answer and more quickly.

Comment: Would you like to send a newsletter to two employees that work for a company with specific additional attributes or the only thing that matters is that the newsletter is sent to two employees which work for the same company?

Answer (score 2):

May be this will help you...

```
DELETE FROM newsletter nl
WHERE ID NOT IN
(
    select id from newsletter ne where ne.comp_name=hl.comp_name limit 2
)
```

I am using table name as examples just replace it with your original name.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query. It is for Sql Server database.

```
select * from Employees e
where id in (select top 2 id from Employees ie where e.company = ie.company)
```

Please replace the table and field names as the exact structure of table is not known.